# Creating a new variable in a dataset in R

Tags: r, tidyr

The dataset I have contains states and I would like for a new variable or column to be called Region, 
Pacific-Oregon, Calif., Washington
Rock Mountains -  Nevada, Montana Idaho, ect

I am confussed on where to go from here. Any ideas?

Comment: You may start by making a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: What do you have and what do you want? Is the new column dependent on values in the columns you already have?

Comment: If state = Calif, Oregon, Washington, then region = Pacific. I have the states listed as a column.

Comment: where is your information about the correspondence between states and regions coming from?

Comment: It would be easier with an example. But for that you can use ifelse() and %in% together.

Answer (score 3):

The classic way to do this would be with `merge()`, or (since you added the `tidyr` tag, so you're in the "Hadleyverse") `dplyr::full_join()`.  Assuming you have one data frame with states and other data:

```
d1 <- data.frame(state=c("Alaska","Massachusetts",
                 "Massachusetts","Florida"),
                 other_stuff=1:4)
```

and another data frame containing the matches between the states and their regions:

```
d2 <- data.frame(state=c("Alaska","Massachusetts","Florida"),
                 region=c("Western","Northeast","Southeast"))
```

Then

```
library("dplyr")
d1 %>% full_join(d2,by="state")
```

should do what you want.

But it's up to you to figure out where to get `d2`, or the equivalent information, from.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact that you did not provide your data I suppose youre data looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(state = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Oregon", "Washington"))
```

I suppose you have a column in your data.frame (in this case called df$state) that has information on the state. You can create a new variable called region like this:

```
df$region[df$state == "California" | df$state == "Oregon" ] <- "Pacific"

df
```

Comment: this solves the problem but doesn't scale very well ...